# Resize from 4-inch to 3.5 using Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, layout, sprite-kit

I'm doing my first iOs game using Sprite Kit and Swift.
I start positioning all my Sprites and labels like:

```
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200)
```

when i run in a 4-inch device, it looks really good but when i run it in a 3.5 device the game looks incomplete.

Is there any good solutions to resize all the layers instead of redesign all my scenes?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change the initial setting for your scene scaleMode, you should have it set to `.aspectFill`. This setting will size your scene keeping it's aspect ration but trying to fill your screen. It will chop part of it basically. There's little you can do except go for an `.aspectFit` setting. It will keep the aspectRation but will fit all your scene in the screen leaving you with black letter boxing bands.

Most people do not use .aspectFit but if you know how to resize the scene depending on the screen size, you can add the needed padding on either side to remove the black letter boxing. I created a framework that does that for you and also calculates your original anchor point for your scene so you loose nothing of your current coordinates implementation. All with 2 methods.. I highly suggest you take a look at it: [SceneSizer](https://github.com/Tokuriku/tokuriku-framework-stash)

Just:

1. Download the ZIP file for the Repository
2. Open the "SceneSizer" sub-folder
3. Drag the SceneSizer.framework "lego block" in your project
4. Make sure that the Framework in Embedded and not just Linked
5. Import the Framework somewhere in your code `import SceneSizer`

And you're done, you can now call the sizer Class with: `SceneSizer.calculateSceneSize(#initialSize: CGSize, desiredWidth: CGFloat, desiredHeight: CGFloat) -> CGSize`

Documentation is in the folder for a clean and full use with a standard scene. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sure thing, tell me if you need help implementing it!

Comment: I am sure the framework is in Embedded but i get this "Opening import file for module 'SceneSizer': Not a directory" ¿Some ideas?
Edit: Forget it, i import the .h header into the Obj-C Bridging header.

Comment: I usually drag the framework in my project at the bottom. I choose copy of course. Then I go see the project target and make sure it's in both in linked and embedded once each. Then in my scene.swift file I do `import SceneSizer`. That's all I do. Mind you I don't know your setup so I can't advise more on this point..